# Prove that there exist an infinite number of $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{2^{n}+1}{n}=k, k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory

I am quite sure that Vieta jumping (not sure if this is quite the right name for what I am doing? It is a jumping of sorts) works for this one, but I cannot prove it. The obvious first solution is $n = 3$, from then on we jump to the solution $n = 2^{3}+1=9$ which also produces a valid solution ($\frac{2^{9}+1}{9}=57$), from then on it follows that $n=2^{513}+1$ is also a solution, and WolframAlpha is able to verify this. I cannot compute the following ones by hand or machine, because the numbers get absolutely humongous very fast, but I have a hunch that this will work towards infinity.

I tried to get a recursive formula for all such $n$:
$$f(n)=2^{f(n-1)}+1,$$
$$f(0)=3$$
but I am also unable to get a nice expression for any $f(n)$ without recursion.

I also tried to do a proof by induction:

Suppose that:
$$\frac{2^{n}+1}{n}=k, k\in \mathbb{N}$$

then prove, that:

$$\frac{2^{2^{n}+1}+1}{2^{n}+1}=j, j\in \mathbb{N}$$

But also didn't get very far. Am I even correct in my assumption that this works in general? If so, how could I prove this? Thank you!

P.S. I am quite aware of the much easier proof by induction when $n=3^{k},k\in \mathbb{N}$, but this is something I happened to notice and it caught my attention.

Comment: Your approach seems good to me and I believe is correct. I would suggest continuing the proof by induction by noticing that if $\frac{2^n+1}{n}\in \mathbb N$, meaning $n$ divides $2^n+1$, then there is some integer $t$ such that $2^n+1=tn$. Try using this to showing that $tn$ divides $2^{tn}+1$.

Comment: Wait... an infinite number of such $n$ for any $k$? That's obviously false.  $\frac {2^n+1}{n} = 5$ has no solutions.  Or an infinite number of such $k$ so that such an $n$ exits?

Comment: I believe the meaning of the question is indeed to prove that there exists an infinity of $n$ such that $n$ divides $2^n+1$.

Comment: Yes, @tjeremie is right. Also, I did try using $tn$ and going the induction route, but that didn't get me very far either, because we know nothing about $t$ without it becoming a circular argument...

Comment: Then that should be the question or the $k$ should quantified "for some $k$".... Hmm, I suppose proving there are infinitely many $n$ so that $n|2^n+1$ is a slightly different question as there are infinitely $k$ so that $k = \frac {2^n+1}n$ for a natural $n$.  But of course the solutions to both would be equivalent as $\frac {2^n+1}n$ are distinct.

Comment: @fleablood When writing the question I meant prove that there is an infinite number of natural $n$ such that $\frac{2^{n}+1}{n}$ is some natural number. It's clear enough to me.

Comment: $\frac{2^{2^{n}+1}+1}{2^{n}+1}= \frac {2^{nk} +1}{2^n+1}$.  Can you prove that is an integer?  When is $\frac {a^k +1}{a+1}$ an integer.  What do you get if you synthetically divide $a^k+1$ by $a+1$?  When do you and when do you not get a remainder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{2^{2^{n}+1}+1}{2^{n}+1}= \frac {2^{nk} +1}{2^n+1}$

Let $a = 2^n$ then we have $\frac{a^k + 1}{a+1}$.  If $k$ is odd then $\frac{a^k + 1}{a+1}= (a+1)(a^{k-1} - a^{k-2} + ....... + a^2 - a + 1)$.

So if $k$ is odd then $\frac {2^{nk} +1}{2^n+1}$ is an integer.

And $nk = 2^n+1$ is odd.  So $k$ is odd too.

=====  previous answer below =====

Well.....

So $3$ is a solution and $2^3 + 1=9$ is a solution.  And as it turns out $2^9 + 1 = 513$ is a solution.

It sure looks like if $n$ is a solution, then $2^n+1$ will be one too.

So lets try by induction:

If $2^{n} + 1 = m$ and $\frac {2^n+1}n = \frac mn = k$ then

$2^m + 1 = 2^{nk} + 1 = (2^n)^k + 1 = (2^n+ 1-1)^k =(m-1)^k + 1$

And $(m-1)^k + 1\equiv 0 \pmod m$.

(Because $m-1\equiv -1\pmod m$ and $k = \frac mn = \frac {2^n+1}n$ is odd.)

That's it.  We're done.  If $n|2^n + 1$ then $(2^n+1)|2^{2^n+1} + 1$.

Comment: How did you get $(m-1)^k + 1\equiv 0 \pmod m$?

Comment: $m-1 \equiv -1\pmod m$ and ..... Arrgh you are right $k$ has to be odd.  .... but $k$ *is* odd because $m=2^n + 1$ is odd so all factors of $m$ are odd and $k=\frac mn$ is odd.   So $(m-1)^k \equiv (-1)^k \equiv -1\pmod m$ and $(m-1)^k + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod m$.

Comment: Right! Thank you, that's an elegant proof.

Answer (score 2):

So let's suppose we have positive integers $n,k$ such that $2^n + 1 = nk$. Then
\begin{align}
2^{2^n+1} + 1
&= 2^{nk} + 1 \\
&= (nk - 1)^k + 1 \\
&= \Biggl(\sum_{m = 0}^{k} \binom{k}{m}(nk)^{k-m}(-1)^{m}\Biggr) + 1 \\
&= \sum_{m = 0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{m}(nk)^{k-m}(-1)^m \tag{$k$ odd} \\
&= (nk)\cdot \sum_{m = 0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{m}(nk)^{k-m-1}(-1)^m \\
&= (2^n+1)\cdot \sum_{m = 0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{m}(nk)^{k-m-1}(-1)^m \\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{2^n+1}\,,
\end{align}
thus whenever $n \mid 2^n + 1$ then $2^n+1 \mid 2^{2^n+1}+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a few more $n$ for which $2^n + 1 \cong 0 \pmod{n}$ ($n$ between listed values do not satisfy that congruence):

1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 171, 243, 513, 729, 1539, 2187, 3249, 4617, 6561, 9747, 13203, 13851, 19683, 29241, 39609, 41553, 59049, 61731, 87723, 97641, 118827, 124659, 177147, 185193, 250857, 263169, 292923, 354537, 356481, 373977, 531441, 555579, 752571, 789507, 878769, 1063611, 1069443, 1121931, 1172889, 1594323, 1666737, 1855179, 2152089, 2257713, 2354697, 2368521, 2636307, 3190833, 3208329, 3365793, 3518667, 4766283, 4782969, 5000211, 5565537, 6456267, 6736203, 6773139, 7064091, 7105563, 7908921, 9572499, 9624987, 10097379, 10556001, 10970073, 14298849, 14348907, 15000633, 16696611, 19368801, 20208609, 20319417, 21192273, 21316689, 22284891, 23726763, 28717497, 28874961, 29884473, 30292137, 31668003, 32910219, 33894369, 35248401, 38265939, 40889691, 42896547, 43046721, 44739243, 45001899, 50089833, 55753011, 57789531, 58106403, 60625827, 60958251, 63576819, 63950067, 66854673, 71180289, 74214171, 86152491, 86624883, 89653419, 90559377, 90876411, 95004009, 98730657, 101683107, 105745203, 114797817, 116226009, 122669073, 127987857, 128689641, 129140163, 134217729, 135005697, 143239347, 150269499, 167259033, 173368593, 174319209, 181877481, 182874753, 190730457, 191850201, 200564019, 208431387, 213540867, 222642513, 258457473, 259874649, 268960257, 271678131, 272629233, 285012027, 296191971, 305049321, 317235609, 344380329, 344393451, 348678027, 350790507, 368007219, 383963571, 386068923, 387420489, 402653187, 405017091, 423412929, 429718041, 450808497, 501777099, 517269483, 520105779, 522957627, 545632443, 548624259, 567804987, 572191371, 575550603, 601692057, 625294161, 640622601, 643993011, 667927539, 669719619, 727052841, 751611177, 775372419, 776904129, 779623947, 806880771, 815034393, 817887699, 850045617, 855036081, 888575913, 892145817, 915147963, 951706827, 1033140987, 1033180353, 1046034081, 1052371521, 1059307209, 1098001089, 1104021657, 1151446833, 1151890713, 1158206769, 1162261467, 1207959561, 1215051273, 1270238787, 1289154123, 1352425491, 1410069249, 1505331297, 1551808449, 1560317337, 1568872881, 1636897329, 1645872777, 1703414961, 1716574113, 1720628163, 1726651809, 1788121899, 1805076171, 1875882483, 1921867803, 1931979033, 2003782617, 2009158857, 2181158523, 2208294171, 2254833531, 2326117257, 2330712387, 2338871841, 2420642313, 2431769283, 2445103179, 2453663097, 2550136851, 2565108243, 2595432537, 2665727739, 2676437451, 2721547593, 2745443889, 2855120481, 3099422961, 3099541059, 3138102243, 3157114563, 3177921627, 3294003267, 3312064971, 3454340499, 3455672139, 3474620307, 3486784401, 3623878683, 3645153819, 3810716361, 3846371913, 3867462369, 3960196353, 4014314433, 4057276473, 4230207747, 4515993891, 4655425347, 4680952011, 4706618643, 4910691987, 4937618331, 5110244883, 5149722339, 5161884489, 5179955427, 5364365697, 5415228513, 5524782147, 5627647449, 5765603409, 5795937099, 6011347851, 6027476571, 6237348057, 6543226251, 6543475569, 6624882513, 6665019633, 6764500593, 6978351771, 6992137161, 7016615523, 7261926939, 7295307849, 7335309537, 7360989291, 7650410553, 7695324729, 7786297611, 7997183217, 8029312353, 8044845651, 8164642779, 8236331667, 8565361443, 9298268883, 9298623177, 9414306729, 9419693553, 9471343689, 9533764881, 9828120177, 9882009801, 9936194913, 10161972027, 10363021497, 10367016417, 10423860921, 10460353203, 10788294753, 10871636049, 10935461457, 11432149083, 11539115739, 11602387107, 11852199369, 11880589059, 12042943299, 12171829419, 12235867209, 12690623241, 12724672761, 13229694441, 13547981673, 13814003979, 13966276041, 14042856033, 14119855929, 14280612363, 14732075961, 14761178451, 14812854993, 15330734649, 15449167017, 15485653467, 15539866281, 16093097091, 16150866723, 16245685539, 16574346441, 16882942347, 16950770523, 17064034083, 17296810227, 17387811297, 18034043553, 18082429713, 18712044171, 18944839467, 19629678753, 19630426707, 19874647539, 19995058899, 20126836971, 20293501779, 20862020691, 20935055313, 20976411483, 21049846569, 21785780817, 21877489827, 21885923547, 22005928611, 22032887841, 22082967873, 22230967347, 22864359897, 22951231659, 23085974187, 23348013561, 23358892833, 23991549651, 24020090001, 24087937059, 24134536953, ...

Interestingly, not all are powers of $3$.

Comment: That's cool, may I ask how you generated this list?

Comment: @DDomjosa : I used the indicated congruence and [right-to-left binary modular multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) to compute the powers of $2$ modulo $n$ quickly.

Comment: Are all of them divisble by 3?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout : Except for $1$, yes, up to $26\,791\,315\,731$.