# Just a general number theory question I came across while playing around a bit. Find all $x$ such that $x \mid 2^x+1$ .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all $x$ such that $x\mid 2^x+1$ .

Naturally, I tried looking for some observation and cyclicity and didn't really come across the solution. Somehow I tried $9$ and it seems it works so I tried to find a pattern for $3k$ (which failed ofc) but ended up with $3^k$ which seems to be right. Although this claim can be proved. I want a complete generalization for the possible solutions not just some sets of it. I tried FLT which doesn't really fit in where as concepts like CRT, Euler Totient, etc. are not very useful here. It would be helpful if I could get some insight on how to approach such problems as well.
P.S : The problem was pretty much a sequence on oeis with some advanced theory. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471316/42969

Comment: If $x=p>2$ is prime, then $2^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so $2^p+1\equiv 3 \pmod p$, just to settle the prime case.

Comment: @MartinR As in the last answer, not all are powers of 3, like I want a complete generalized formula such that all answer sets including that of $3^t$ are included

Comment: @lulu $2^p \equiv 2 \ (mod \ p)$ therefore p=3 is only prime case here. This is ofc right and very intuitive but is a very small branch to the main solution. Could you provide some more insight into the generalized version of solutions.

Comment: This is [A006521](https://oeis.org/A006521).

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! Btw can this statement "For instance, every element of this sequence apart from 1 and 3 is divisible either by 171 or 243 or 13203 or 2354697 or 10970073 or 22032887841" be proved?

Comment: See the papers cited on the EOIS page linked above. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879508/pattern-of-divisibility-within-2n1-equiv0-pmodn/3879665#3879665).

Comment: "For instance, every element of this sequence apart from 1 and 3 is divisible either by 171 or 243 or 13203 or 2354697 or 10970073 or 22032887841" be proved? We also have to exclude $9,27,81$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly x must be coprime with 2 so x is an odd number

We can prove for $x=3^k$ using euler's theorem and induction $k\gt1$

$$
\phi(3^k)=3^k(1-\frac{1}3)=2\cdot3^{k-1}\\
2^{\phi(3^{k+1})}\equiv1 \bmod(3^{k+1})\\
(2^{3^k})^2\equiv1 \bmod(3^{k+1})\\
(3^k\lambda-1)^2\equiv1 \bmod(3^{k+1})\\
-2\cdot3^k\lambda\equiv0 \bmod(3^{k+1})\\
$$

So $3|\lambda$ which gives

$$
2^{3^k}+1\equiv0\bmod(3^{k+1})\\
\text{cube on both sides}\\
2^{3^{k+1}}+3\cdot2^{3^k}(2^{3^k}+1)+1\equiv2^{3^{k+1}}+3^{k+1}C\lambda+1\equiv2^{3^{k+1}}+1\equiv0\bmod(3^{k+1})
$$

This completes the induction and gives an elementary insight $3^{k+1}|2^{3^k}+1$

note:this is a partial solution but im working on a full one cant seem to quite get it ill edit if i do